# Ncurses: movement

Tags: c++, animation, sprite

I have a problem with programming movement using C++ and Ncurses.
I'm programming a pacman and the main problem is, that I just want last pressed key in time period.

When I use **usleep**, it saves every key pressed during sleeping and then it's working with that in the order.

Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you in no-delay mode? If so, this might work:

```
usleep(your_delay);
last_key = ERR;
while ( (key=getch()) != ERR ) {
  last_key = key;
}
// "last_key" now holds most recent key, if there was one, else ERR
```

Comment: And is there any possibility to make it using delay mode? (out of curiosity)

Answer (score 1):

What did you try?

Something like this should work, if I understood correctly what you try to achieve:

```
int t = your_delay;
while (t --> 0)
{
    sleep(1);
    c = getch();
}
```

If you really need to time it down to the microsecond, this might not be the best approach, but if you can have some tolerance, this should be enough.